# python redis and command PUBSUB channels

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm testing `redis-py`: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.

I have a hard time figuring out how to call and get output for the `redis` command `PUBSUB channels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all channels:

```py
chans = r.pubsub_channels()
```

To get the number of subscribers to a channel:

```py
num = r.pubsub_numsub('channel')
```

Comment: This I know. I need the command `PUBSUB channels` so I can get a list of channels and numbers of subscribers.

Comment: @AlfredBalle ahh I misunderstood and thought you meant just channel operations in general. Updated my answer